# Spring repository not always throwing DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-data, spring-restcontroller

I'm making a REST API with Spring and I have trouble unit testing it.
I wrote an endpoint to update user groups and it does send a 409 conflict when I create a group with a duplicate name in my frontend (unique=true). However when I do the unit test it doesn't. I found out that adding this line `groupRepository.findAll().forEach(g -> System.out.println(g.getName()));` at the end of the unit test does throw a 409.

Endpoint:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Object> update(@ApiParam(value = "form object to add to the store", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody FormGroupDTO group, @ApiParam(value = "Id of the form that needs to be updated", required = true) @PathVariable("groupId") Long groupId, @ApiParam(value = "token to be passed as a header", required = true) @RequestHeader(value = "token", required = true) String token) {
    String name = JWTutils.getEmailInToken(token);

    if(name == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(name);

    if(user == null){
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    FormGroup groupModel = groupRepository.findByIdAndAdmin(groupId, user);

    if(groupModel == null){
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }

    if(group.getMembers().stream().filter(m -> m.getRole() == UserFormGroupRole.ADMIN).toArray().length == 0){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ValidationErrorDTO("noAdmin", "MEMBER.NOADMIN"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // Get users
    groupModel.getUserFormGroups().clear();
    for(MemberDTO member : group.getMembers()){
        User u = userRepository.findByEmail(member.getEmail());
        if(u == null){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ValidationErrorDTO("notexist", "ADDUSER.NOTEXIST"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        if(u.getRole() == UserRole.USER){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new ValidationErrorDTO("notexist", "ADDUSER.NOTPRIVILEGED"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        UserFormGroup ufg = userFormGroupRepository.findByUserAndFormGroup(u, groupModel);
        if(ufg == null){
            groupModel.getUserFormGroups().add(new UserFormGroup(u, groupModel, member.getRole()));
        } else{
            ufg.setRole(member.getRole());
            groupModel.getUserFormGroups().add(ufg);
        }
    }

    groupModel.setName(group.getName());

    try{
        groupRepository.save(groupModel);
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getClass());
        return  new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

My unit test:

```
@Test
public void updateGroupNameAlreadyInUse() throws Exception {
    groupRepository.save(new FormGroup("newFormGroup", user));
    this.mockMvc.perform(put("/groups/" + group.getId())
            .header("token", token)
            .content(json(new FormGroupDTO("newFormGroup", group.getUserFormGroups().stream().map(ufg -> new MemberDTO(ufg.getUser().getEmail(), ufg.getRole())).collect(Collectors.toList()))))
            .contentType(contentType))
            .andExpect(status().isConflict());
}
```

The save function of my CrudRepository doesn't always throws DataIntegrityViolationException. I just realised that maybe the first line of my unit test `groupRepository.save(new FormGroup("newFormGroup", user));` might not be executed before the end of my unit test and the `findAll` function triggers it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short story: you need to manually do `flush()` after inserts in the tests. Now let's discuss in details. I assume you're using ID Generation strategy like Sequence or UUID or something like this.

There are multiple things to consider:

## Flush

- FlushMode - determines when ORM triggers the SQL statements. By default it triggers before any `SELECT` statement and before the transaction commit. Your solution with getting the name of each record issues a `SELECT` statement - which triggers flushing of all the pending SQL statements.
- `save()` or `persist()` guarantees that a persistent object is returned. Such an object must have an ID. Some ID Generation Strategies (like `Identity`) require an `INSERT` statement to generate the ID. Others (like `Sequence`, `UUID`) - don't. So ORM can get an ID without inserting the record (which it wants to delay as much as possible for some optimizations).

So when doing testing that's related to ORMs you must invoke `flush()` manually before doing anything with that data.

## Transactions & Sessions

When you mark things as `@Transactional` the behaviour is:

1. See if the transaction is already opened in this thread.

   - If yes - don't do anything.
   - If no - create a transaction and bind it to current thread (via ThreadLocal variable).
2. When method is finished - check if transaction was started by me.

   - If not - do nothing.
   - If yes - commit the transaction, close the session.

I assume you mark your test with `@Transactional`. Which means it's test who starts the session and transaction. Repository just uses the already opened one. Then since there is no commit - there is no flush. Then you use MockMvc - **that works in the same thread**. It goes through `@Transactional` or `OSIV` which also find that transaction has already been started. So the transaction is reused.

Then it goes to your core logic - there you're doing some `SELECT` statements and this flushes the pending SQL Statements in current session. So your original `save()` just flushed.

Now in the end of your logic you're again doing `save()` which puts an INSERT statement into the pending SQL queries. When the tests is finished it just rolls back the transaction and the final `INSERT` doesn't happen. Unless.. You're doing your `SELECT` statements that you mentioned.

So finally - don't forget to do `flush()` and `clear()` in your ORM-related tests. These methods are present in Hibernate's `Session` or JPA's `EntityManager`. The former can be done with: `SessionFactory#getCurrentSession()`.The latter can be injected with:

```
@PersistenceContext 
EntityManager entityManager;
```

PS: I didn't see any production code that's marked with `@Transactional`. You may run into issues if you don't do this.

PPS: [this is not a unit test](http://qala.io/blog/holes-in-test-terminology.html).

Comment: I do have the `@Transactional` on my test class. Now I understand why it doesn't work, thank you! How can I flush manually, there don't seem to be any method to achieve this with CrudRepository and I have no EntityManager instance.

Comment: `@PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;` Added this to the answer.

PS: Before using crap like SpringData and SpringBoot you'd rather work with usual Hibernate and Spring. Otherwise everything will look like magic to you.